# Pass entire table data to action method using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

This question might be dumb but since i am new to JS and Jquery i have been struggling to get it done.

I have a table in a page where user can edit cell values in place(I am using contenteditable attribute).
There is a Save All button, on click on which I want to send current values in all the rows of the table to server side action method.

Please suggest me on how to achieve this or a better way of achieving the same functionality.

Comment: You would need to serialize the table to [JSON](http://www.json.org/) and send that to your action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `Save All` button is clicked, you can do something like this:

```
$("#saveAllBtnId").click ( function () {

// read the data from the table using loop
  $('#myTable > tbody  > tr').each(function() {

  // here retrieve the values from the table cells 
  // Example
  var cellValue = $(this).... // you need to fill this code as per your table structure 

  // store all the data in an array
  var mydata = new Array ( cellValue, ....);
  var jsonData = JSON.stringify(mydata);

  // send the data to backend, e.g.
  $.post ("back/end/code", { data : jsonData }, function () {});

  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot. This is what i wanted. However, a little modification was needed while creating array.Below is the working code.

```
        function btnClicked() {
        // read the data from the table using loop
        var mydata = [];
        $('#testTable > tbody  > tr').each(function() {

            // here retrieve the values from the table cells 
            // Example
            var name = ($(this).find(".name").html());
            var age = ($(this).find(".age").html());

            var obj = { name: name, age: age };

            // store all the data in an array
            mydata.push(obj);


        });
        var jsonData = JSON.stringify(mydata);

        // send the data to backend, e.g. 
        //for now adding an alert
        for (var i = 0 ; i < mydata.length; i++) {

            alert(mydata[i].name + mydata[i].age);
        }
        $.post ("Test/SomeAction", { data : jsonData }, function () {});

    }
```